# Format string vulnerability with %n - why can start of format string be used to specify write address?

Tags: c, printf

On the Wikipedia page for [Uncontrolled format string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncontrolled_format_string) it says:

> The start of the format string is crafted to contain the address that
>   the %n format token can then overwrite with the address of the
>   malicious code to execute.

Why does this work? How does printf end up using the start of the string as the address to overwrite?

Comment: See http://julianor.tripod.com/bc/tn-usfs.pdf for more info.